# SQL Server: One large persisted computed column for Fulltext Indexing

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, fulltext-index, calculated-columns, persisted-column

It appears to me as the easiest, most straightforward solution, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Instead of having a fulltext index on all individual columns of a table, isn't it better to just generate one single wide computed column and run the fulltext index against that only?

It appears to me that it gets rid of all the issues of having multiple columns, incl. that I can't search "x AND y" as this will not match a row with "x" present in column 1 and "y" present in column 2.

Any counterarguments?

Comment: We can't answer this, because you haven't told us what you're trying to do, much less your priorities (e.g, I prefer to sacrifice size for speed).

Comment: FTS provides ranking, with you wouldn't get using a concatenated column...

Comment: @tpdi: I wanted to know if my argument is flawed in some way. OMG Ponies provided one counterargument. That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FTS provides ranking and weighting](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2006/12/30/sql-server-full-text-search-protips-part-3-getting-ranked/), with you wouldn't get using a concatenated column...